# How to display custom player controls on youtube chromeless player using Flash builder 4.6?

Tags: youtube, flex4, youtube-api, flash-builder, flex4.6

I have a View component which initialises [youtube cloud api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference) using "http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1" url and plays the video fullscreen. It has play, pause and progress bar under `s:actionContent`, but I am trying to put "rewind", "play/pause", "forward" and a interactive progress bar on top of the chromeless player itself (transparent popup with image buttons for the same), like the below image. 
[image]

My View component which initialises youtube api does not have any items. (Removed `s:actionContent` to try out popup)

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="YoutubeVideoPlay" viewActivate="init()" >
    <fx:Script source="YoutubePlayer.as"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            //navigator.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,showPlayerControl);     How to add a event listener on the youtube player?
            public function showPlayerControl():void{
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(PlayerControls,player);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:View>
```

Need help with this popup manager to appear on top of chromeless player, when the user taps on the playing video.

```
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="400" height="300">
    <fx:Script source="../YoutubePlayer.as"/>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        global
        {
            modal-transparency: 0.0;
            modal-transparency-color: white;
            modal-transparency-blur: 0;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[               
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            /*[Bindable][Embed(source="view/assets/images/play32.png")]
            public static var iconPlay : Class;*/
            [Bindable][Embed(source="view/assets/images/pause32.png")]
            public static var iconPause : Class;
            [Bindable][Embed(source="view/assets/images/forward32.png")]
            public static var iconForward : Class;
            [Bindable][Embed(source="view/assets/images/rewind32.png")]
            public static var iconRewind : Class;               
            //addEventListener(FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE,removePlayerControls);
            /*private function removePlayerControls(event:FlexMouseEvent):void {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }*/             
            public function closeAndBackup():void {
                dispose();
                navigator.popView();                                
            }
            public function initAndPlay():void {                
                player.playVideo();

            }               
            private var _duration:String = "";

            [Bindable]
            public function get duration():String {
                return _duration;
            }               
            public function set duration(val:String):void {
                _duration = val;

            }
            protected function ytVideoSlider_changeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                trace(event.currentTarget.value);
                player.seekTo(event.currentTarget.value,true);              
            }
        ]]>     
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingLeft="10"/>
            </s:layout>
            <s:HSlider id="ytVideoSlider" 
                       liveDragging="true"
                       dataTipPrecision="1"
                       maximum="{duration}"
                       change="ytVideoSlider_changeHandler(event)"/>
            <s:Label text="{Math.round(ytVideoSlider.value)}"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:Button icon="{iconRewind}" click="player.playVideo()"/>
        <s:Button icon="{iconPause}" click="player.pauseVideo()"/>
        <s:Button icon="{iconForward}" click="closeAndBackup()"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Panel>
```

Any help will be appreciated. :)

I have just started with Flash Builder's spark components, so pardon me if my question is too lame.

Or Is there any link/tutorial available to place player controls on top of chromeless youtube player?

**Update: I was able to solve my problem, and provided my solution too**

Comment: Especially since you put a bounty on the question you should comment on the answers, to clarify what they are missing.

Comment: @MarkFox: Actually I was able to solve my problem just after putting a bounty on this question. It's similar to answer given by Colin. I'll post my answer too.

Comment: Classic problem solving conundrum. Asking the question helps me self-solve problems all the time.

Comment: @MarkFox: Yes :) I added my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a click listener to the entire view. While I have never used this API before, I would imagine it would look something like this:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="YoutubeVideoPlay"
viewActivate="init()" click="showPlayerControl()">

<fx:Script source="YoutubePlayer.as"/>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function showPlayerControl():void{
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(PlayerControls,player);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're nearly there. What you need to remember is that the YouTube player has its own interactions, eg when the user clicks the video it usually pauses/resumes. Now you can get around this by placing an invisible `Sprite` on top of the video as this'll allow you to capture the user's mouse movements and clicks.

The only issue with this is the current state of autoplaying; at the moment (and for the future I guess) autoplays don't count as views against the video. The user needs to press the play button on the YouTube video to actually make that count as a view.

So what I do is only add this invisible `Sprite` once playback has commenced. You can then also be clever and send pause/resume events to the player itself when the user clicks on your invisible `Sprite`.

Regarding the UI components that you're after: they're very easy to put together, you can always grab standard UI Flash/Flex components and hook them up to the player API (I see you've made a start); it's always a good idea, though, to get a design in you head rather than sketching out UIs over and over again in code.

As a footnote: you're always welcome to use my middleware class for the YouTube player on github: https://github.com/ahmednuaman/AS3/blob/master/com/firestartermedia/lib/as3/display/component/video/YouTubePlayerAS3.as

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my question

I have a `PlaylistsView.mxml` which has a List with all the videos. Once clicked it pushes a new view called `YtPlayView.mxml`

```
<!--YtPlayView.mxml-->  
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:popup="views.popup.*"
    title="{data.title}" viewActivate="init()" viewDeactivate="deactivateYoutubePlayer()">
    <fx:Script source="ytfeeds/YoutubePlayer.as"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function deactivateYoutubePlayer():void{
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(ytcPopup);
                dispose();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

In `YoutubePlayer.as`, `onPlayerReady(event:Event)` I add a mouseclick eventlistener  `player.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showPlayerControl);`

```
    <!--YoutubePlayer.as contents-->
public function showPlayerControl(event:MouseEvent):void{
    ytcPopup=new PlayerControls();
    ytcPopup.player=player;
    ytcPopup.duration=data.duration;                
    ytcPopup.currentPosition="00:00:00";        
    ytcPopup.open(this,true);
    ytcPopup.width = this.stage.width;
    ytcPopup.setStyle("modalTransparency",0);
    ytcPopup.setStyle("modalTransparencyBlur",3);
    ytcPopup.setStyle("modalTransparencyColor", "#ff0000");
    if(ytcPopup.player.getPlayerState()==1){        
        ytcPopup.playPauseBtn.setStyle("icon",ytcPopup.iconPause);
    }
    else if(ytcPopup.player.getPlayerState()==2){       
        ytcPopup.playPauseBtn.setStyle("icon",ytcPopup.iconPlay);
    }
    ytcPopup.y = this.stage.height-195;
    PopUpManager.bringToFront(ytcPopup);        
    if(player.getCurrentTime()!=0)
        ytcPopup.ytVideoSlider.value=player.getCurrentTime();       
}
```

Which  gives me something like below (It's a portrait view, on Landscape view it comes on top of the video)

If anyone wants more source code or help, i'll be happy to help :) Just drop a comment.

[image]